# Select box not being updated after I add an option to it javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Basically, I am adding an option to a select box and while the data is being added in the array of options, the new added option is not appearing on screen:
here is a Jfiddle of my code:https://jsfiddle.net/6u383mgj/.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.modal').modal();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').material_select();
});

function CategoryChange() {
  var y = document.getElementById("plid");
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if (y.length > 1) {
      y.remove(y.length - 1);
    }
  }
  var categoriesvar = document.getElementById("category");
  var value = categoriesvar.options[categoriesvar.selectedIndex].value;
  alert(value);
  if (value == "Prop") {
    dropdownforprop();
    var x = document.getElementById("plid");
    alert(x.options[2].value);

  } else if (value == "Software") {
    dropdownforsoft();
    var x = document.getElementById("plid");
    alert(x.options[2].value);
  } else if (value == "Arts") {
    dropdownforarts();
    var x = document.getElementById("plid");
    alert(x.options[2].value);
  }
};

function dropdownforprop() {
  var select = document.getElementById('plid');
  select.options[0].innerHTML = "What type of prop are you looking for?";
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Electronic', 'Electronic');
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Wooden', 'Wooden');
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Metal', 'Metal');
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Clothes', 'Clothes');
}

function dropdownforsoft() {
  var select = document.getElementById('plid');
  select.options[0].innerHTML = "What language are you looking for?";
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Assembly', 'Assembly');
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('C#', 'C#');
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('C++', 'C++');
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Java', 'Java');
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('JavaScript', 'JavaScript');
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Ruby', 'Ruby');
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Python', 'Python');
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('VHDL', 'VHDL');
}

function dropdownforarts() {
  var select = document.getElementById('plid');
  select.options[0].innerHTML = "What type of arts are you looking for?";
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Music', 'Music');
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Painting', 'Painting');
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Poster', 'Poster');
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Sculptures', 'Sculptures');

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-field col s6">
  <select id="category" name="Categories" onchange="CategoryChange()">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose a category</option>
                <option value="Arts">Arts</option>
                <option value="Prop">Prop</option>
                <option value="Software">Software</option>
              </select>
  <label>Category</label>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s6">
  <select id="plid">
                <option value="" disabled selected>You must choose a category first</option>
              </select>
  <label id="subcategorylabel">Sub-Category</label>
</div>
```

the way it's supposed to work is that when someone chooses a main category , the sub category select box will be populated. 
if you think there is a better way to do this please tell me. I've been programming with javascript for exactly 7hrs so all help is welcome.

Comment: I suggest to use Select2; https://select2.org/data-sources/arrays

Answer (score 0):

I don't know more about jsfiddle, but look like there something misconfigured.

If you change a little bit where you define your code, all will work fine.

```
  <script>
      function  CategoryChange(){
    var y = document.getElementById("plid");
    for(var i=0;i<8;i++){
      if (y.length > 1) {
      y.remove(y.length-1);
  }}
    var categoriesvar = document.getElementById("category");
    var value = categoriesvar.options[categoriesvar.selectedIndex].value;
      alert(value);
      if(value=="Prop"){
        dropdownforprop();
        var x = document.getElementById("plid");
        alert(x.options[2].value);

     }
     else if (value=="Software"){
       dropdownforsoft();
       var x = document.getElementById("plid");
       alert(x.options[2].value);
    }
     else if(value=="Arts"){
       dropdownforarts();
         var x = document.getElementById("plid");
         alert(x.options[2].value);
      }
  };
function dropdownforprop(){
      var select = document.getElementById('plid');
      select.options[0].innerHTML="What type of prop are you looking for?";
      select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Electronic', 'Electronic');
      select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Wooden', 'Wooden');
      select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Metal', 'Metal');
      select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Clothes', 'Clothes');
}
function dropdownforsoft(){
    var select = document.getElementById('plid');
  select.options[0].innerHTML="What language are you looking for?";
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Assembly', 'Assembly');
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('C#', 'C#');
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('C++', 'C++');
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Java', 'Java');
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('JavaScript', 'JavaScript');
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Ruby', 'Ruby');
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Python', 'Python');
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('VHDL', 'VHDL');
}
function dropdownforarts(){
    var select = document.getElementById('plid');
  select.options[0].innerHTML="What type of arts are you looking for?";
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Music', 'Music');
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Painting', 'Painting');
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Poster', 'Poster');
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Sculptures', 'Sculptures');

}
  </script>

  <div class="input-field col s6">
              <select id="category" name="Categories" onchange="CategoryChange()">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose a category</option>
                <option value="Arts">Arts</option>
                <option value="Prop">Prop</option>
                <option value="Software">Software</option>
              </select>
              <label>Category</label>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <select id="plid" >
                <option value="" disabled selected>You must choose a category first</option>
              </select>
              <label id="subcategorylabel">Sub-Category</label>
            </div>
```